Find and replace multiple field property values based on the user choice
I have con.properties file as below.
data1=users
data2=admins
 

When a user clicks on batch file provided, values of the above have to be changed based on the area.
if user selected country1 con.properties file has to be changed as below
data1=hello
data2=bye

if user selected country2 con.properties file has to be changed as below
data1=users
data2=admins

I have tried this:
@ECHO OFF

SET /P area="Choose a country (type Country1, Country2): "

2>NUL CALL :%area% # jump to :Country1, :Country2, :England, etc.
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 CALL :DEFAULT_CASE # If label doesn't exist

ECHO Done.
EXIT /B

:Country1
  powershell -Command "& {(Get-Content "con.properties") -replace 'users','hello'  | Out-File -FilePath con.properties;}"
  GOTO END_CASE
:Country2
  powershell -Command "& {(Get-Content "con.properties") -replace 'users','bye'  | Out-File -FilePath con.properties;}"
  GOTO END_CASE
:DEFAULT_CASE
  ECHO Wrong Case
  GOTO END_CASE
:END_CASE
  VER > NUL # reset ERRORLEVEL
  GOTO :EOF # return from CALL

Above script replacing values mentioned in the argument but it has to replace the values based the data1 and data2

What's the point of doing it partially in PowerShell and outdated batch? Just use PowerShell entirel and it should get much easier.

@ECHO OFF

SET /P area="Choose a country (type Country1, Country2): "

2>NUL CALL :%area% # jump to :Country1, :Country2, :England, etc.
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 CALL :DEFAULT_CASE # If label doesn't exist

ECHO Done.
EXIT /B

:Country1
  powershell -C  ^& ^{(cat 'noc.properties'^).replace('users','hello'^)^|Out-File -FilePath .\'noc.properties'^}
  GOTO END_CASE
:Country2
  powershell -C  ^& ^{(cat 'noc.properties'^).replace('users','bye'^)^|Out-File -FilePath .\'noc.properties'^}
  GOTO END_CASE
:England1
  powershell -C ^& ^{(cat 'noc.properties'^).replace('hello','users'^)^|Out-File -FilePath .\'noc.properties'^}
  GOTO END_CASE
:England2
  powershell -C ^& ^{(cat 'noc.properties'^).replace('bye','admins'^)^|Out-File -FilePath .\'noc.properties'^}
  GOTO END_CASE
:DEFAULT_CASE
  ECHO Wrong Case
  GOTO END_CASE
:END_CASE
  VER > NUL # reset ERRORLEVEL
  GOTO :EOF # return from CALL


Note that the editing is done focusing only on the non-functionality of your current code, however the edits only focus on these points listed below and added England options (1,2) to allow loop testing of changes.

Why use CON device name for file name? This makes PowerShell not see your file, it will find the use of "?,*" wildcards in the forms con*.properties and con?.properties, but con.properties it doesn't even list in the dir con.properties command.

Pay attention to syntaxes where they require the use of escapes relevant to characters (including operators) in calls to PowerShell

The current code posted in response has been tested and works for the noc.properties file name, and it simply doesn't work for the original name con.properties



Note: as lo-ol said in his answer is 'Con' a reserved name that shouldn't be used for a file name, so I changed the file name to 'noc.properties'
@ECHO OFF

SET /P area="Choose a country (type Country1, Country2): "

2>NUL CALL :%area% # jump to :Country1, :Country2, :England, etc.
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 CALL :DEFAULT_CASE # If label doesn't exist

ECHO Done.
EXIT /B

:Country1
  powershell -Command "& {(Get-Content 'noc.properties') -replace 'data1=.*$','data1=hello' -replace 'data2=.*$','data2=bye'  | Set-Content 'noc.properties'}"
  GOTO END_CASE
:Country2
  powershell -Command "& {(Get-Content 'noc.properties') -replace 'data1=.*$','data1=hello' -replace 'data2=.*$','data2=bye'  | Set-Content 'noc.properties'}"
  GOTO END_CASE
:DEFAULT_CASE
  ECHO Wrong Case
  GOTO END_CASE
:END_CASE
  VER > NUL # reset ERRORLEVEL
  GOTO :EOF # return from CALL

Or a shorter syntax
@ECHO OFF

SET /P area="Choose a country (type Country1, Country2): "

powershell -Command "$data1, $data2 = switch ($env:area) { Country1 {'hello','bye'} Country2 {'users','admins'} default {Write-Error 'Wrong Case'-EA 1}} ; sc 'noc.properties' ( (gc 'noc.properties') -replace 'data1=.*$',('data1='+$data1) -replace 'data2=.*$',('data2='+$data2) )"

ECHO Done.
EXIT /B

  GOTO END_CASE
:END_CASE
  VER > NUL # reset ERRORLEVEL
  GOTO :EOF # return from CALL


gc : Cannot find path 'C:\Users\ecker\Desktop\SU2024\Q1850914\con.properties' because it does not exist.  In the 1st proposed codes the file "con.{strings}" is not found... in particular, the 2nd one doesn't even execute the powershel call because it has an EXIT /B before invoking powershell, if you remove EXIT /B, powershell also doesn't find the  "con.{strings}" file.

@lo-ol Of Course the code assumes that you have a file named 'con.properties' as this was the question, you should change the name to your file, about your second argument, you are right, I updated the code.

I have this file: con.properties

force the error display with  2>&1 in your command: 2>&1 powershell -Command .... and see the error that returns...

@lo-lo Yes, you are right. 'Con' is a reserved name that shouldn't be used for a file name. I tested it with my own text file and didn't realize that the file name matters. I will update my answer.
However, the questioner said, "Above script replacing values mentioned in the argument but it has to replace the values based the data1 and data2." So, his code actually somehow works for him. He only asked how to replace the values based on the data1 and data2, which is what my answer is focusing on. Your answer, although it's good points, doesn't address the questioner's actual question.

If you had read the answer I proposed to the author of the question, you would have had a different result in your relevant tests.

Thanks. I will try try this
